# Office 365 Email Stats

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to count total emails sent and received from a specific email account per a period. The code is working but giving a bit of overstated result. Please, look at the code below if it could provide correct result. 
I know that I could use the $Allmessages only once without filtering by SenderAddress and then by RecipientAddress but it's running forever without the filtering.

```
    $Allmessages_sent = @()  
    $P = 1  
    do  
   {
    $pagedmessages_sent = Get-MessageTrace -SenderAddress $emailgroup -StartDate $StartDate -EndDate $EndDate -PageSize 1000 -Page $p `
            | Select Received,SenderAddress,RecipientAddress,Size
    $Allmessages_sent += $pagedmessages_sent 
    $p = $p + 1  
   }  
    until ($pagedmessages_sent -eq $null)  
    $senderssorted = 0;
    $senderssorted = $Allmessages_sent |group senderaddress | select @{n="SentCount";e={$_.Count}} 
    $Allmessages_rcvd = @()  
    $P_ = 1  
   do  
   {  
    $pagedmessages_rcvd = Get-MessageTrace -RecipientAddress $emailgroup -StartDate $StartDate -EndDate $EndDate -PageSize 1000 -Page $p_ `
            | Select Received,SenderAddress,RecipientAddress,Size
    $Allmessages_rcvd += $pagedmessages_rcvd
    $p_ = $p_ + 1  
    }  
    until ($pagedmessages_rcvd -eq $null)  
    $recipientsorted = 0;
    $recipientsorted = $Allmessages_rcvd |group recipientaddress | select @{n="ReceivedCount";e={$_.Count}};
    $totalSent = 0; 
    $totalRsvd = 0;
    $totalSent = $senderssorted.Sentcount;
    $totalRsvd = $recipientsorted.ReceivedCount;
    $arrayResult = @();
    $arrayResult += $totalSent;
    $arrayResult += $totalRsvd
    Write-Host "Sent: " $arrayResult[0];
    Write-Host "Received: " $arrayResult[1];
```

Thanks

Comment: what results do you get? what you want to be the final results, show some example...

Comment: E.g., I'm checking my email account for a specific date and I can see that I received 10 emails for the day but the code result is showing 13. I did check the Deleted folder as well. I did sent 4 emails during that day. The code is counting Recipients so I'm counting them too. So, with all recipients that received my those 4 emails it's 9 but the code result is showing 15.

Comment: All was Ok when we did stats from Exchange 2016 applying -Eventid “receive”  -Source "storedriver" and -Eventid “deliver”  -Source "storedriver" accordingly. We also added 3 hours time difference due to a server location. I'm applying the same 3 hours difference now as well. But, probably there could be more filtering needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. The discrepancies explained:
-   The Total ‘Received’ discrepancies were due to the ‘Failed’ status emails were counted. So, I added -Status ‘Delivered’ for the both parts “Get-MessageTrace -SenderAddress …” and also “Get-MessageTrace -RecipientAddress”.
-   The Total ‘Sent’ discrepancies were due to the forwarded emails via setup ‘Rules’ from my mail-box that I wasn’t able to see in my Outlook ‘Sent’ folder.